# Crash trying to open Webview - Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.WebViewRender+WebClient

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.forms

I have an issue with Xamarin.Forms

I'm trying to open a webpage in a NavigationModal but it crash with this error message:

> Could not load signature of Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.WebViewRender+WebClient:OnReceivedError due to: Could not resolve type with token 0100016d (from typeref, class/assembly Android.Webkit.WebResourceError, Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublickKeyToken=84e04ffcfb79065 type:Android.Webkit.WebResourceError member:

My code is:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ContactPage()
        {
            Content = new WebView()
            {
                Source = "http://google.com"
            }
        });
```

- Using PCL
- Target Android version: Android 6.0 (API Level 23)
- Minimum Android version: Android 4.4 (API Level 19)
- Xamarin.Forms v2.3.5.239-pre (and happend the same issue with other versions)
- I'm using Samsung Galaxy S7 edge with Android 6.0 for test

I don't know why is happening because it worked before.

Comment: Did you update your Xamarin.Android recently? I have a project running a code similar as yours and even updated to the latest forms and I am not having any problem. `Xamarin.Android Version: 7.3.1.2` on `Xamarin Studio Version 6.3`

Comment: No. I created a new project with the same Xamarin.Android version and it works fine. I tried to much things but nothing works. One day just not working any more.

Answer (score 1):

After hours I found the target version was pointing to version 5.0. This in Android Project > Options > Application > Compile using... I set to "Use latest platform (7.1)"